# Excel Automation: Protect single worksheet from deletion by user

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

**VSTO 4.0 / Office 2007**

In an Excel document-level automation project, I have a worksheet that **must not be deleted from the workbook**. I am afraid that a careless user might delete it by accident, which currently causes a lot of grief (exceptions galore).

I can not protect the entire workbook, because the user must be able to create, delete and otherwise modify this file. Exactly *one sheet* needs to be protected from deletion, but I may be overlooking something, so if there exists such solution I'm all ears. For example I could imagine that I can `Protect()` and `Unprotect()` the workbook when the sheet is visible, but this solution seems messy.

Googling [yielded](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming/401664-prevent-sheet-deletion.html) the following VBA code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim CB As CommandBar
Dim Ctrl As CommandBarControl
For Each CB In Application.CommandBars
Set Ctrl = CB.FindControl(ID:=847, recursive:=True)
If Not Ctrl Is Nothing Then
Ctrl.OnAction = "RefuseToDelete"
Ctrl.State = msoButtonUp
End If
Next
End Sub
```

I'm not familiar with VBA, but I tried running this from the VSTO generated startup method:

```
private void Sheet1_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    //Is there a neater way to iterate through all Office Collections?
    for (var i = 1; i <= Application.CommandBars.Count; i++)
    {
        var commandBar = Application.CommandBars[i];
        //847 is a magical constant that any fule no has something to do with sheet deletion
        var control = commandBar.FindControl(Id: 847, Recursive: true);
        if (control != null) control.OnAction = null;
    }
}
```

This code seems to do exactly nothing. You may ask *"Hey, Gleno, why are you setting `OnAction` to null"* , well I don't know what to set it to... The linked VBA solution attaches to Activate and Deactivate events, so there's more code where that came from.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do something very similar today. I would just disable the sheet delete buttons whenever your one "undeleteable" sheet is active. If there's a keyboard shortcut to delete a sheet, I can't find one. (If there is, you could disable that too.)

This would go in your ThisWorkbook class:

```
    private void ThisWorkbook_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.SheetActivate += (sh) =>
            {
                this.ribbon.InvalidateBuiltinControl("SheetDelete");
            };
    }

    public bool CanDeleteActiveSheet()
    {
        if (this.ActiveSheet == null)
            return true;

        // Replace Sheet1 with your sheet's CodeName
        return ((Excel.Worksheet)this.ActiveSheet).CodeName != "Sheet1";
    }

    // Keep a local reference to the ribbon in your ThisWorkbook class
    // so you can call InvalidateControl() from it.
    Ribbon ribbon;
    protected override IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
    {
        this.ribbon = new Ribbon();
        return this.ribbon;
    }
```

This would go in your ribbon code behind:

```
    public void InvalidateBuiltinControl(string controlID)
    {
        this.ribbon.InvalidateControlMso(controlID);
    }

    public bool deleteButton_GetEnabled(IRibbonControl control)
    {
        return Globals.ThisWorkbook.CanDeleteActiveSheet();
    }
```

And this would go in your ribbon xml:

```
<commands>
    <command idMso="SheetDelete" getEnabled="deleteButton_GetEnabled" />
</commands>
```

I'm still a little leery of holding on to that ribbon reference in ThisWorkbook, but so far no one has mentioned a better way in [the question I posted earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610938/whats-the-proper-way-to-retrieve-a-reference-to-a-ribbon-object). Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Nick. If I'd ever have to work with the office object model again, that'll be too soon. :)

Comment: Hahaha. I'll tell ya, it's faaaar better now than it was a few years ago!

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a similar problem where I know how to protect the worksheet but I need to turn protection on after the sheet has been populated with external data from a SQL connection.  I cannot locate the correct event to do this.

This should help you put it in the startup event for the worksheet:

Me.Protect(password:="password", allowFiltering:=True, allowSorting:=True, allowUsingPivotTables:=True)