# What's the "proper" way to retrieve a reference to a ribbon object?

Tags: c#, vsto, excel-2010, excel

For a VSTO workbook project, is there a best practice for retrieving a reference to the Ribbon object from the ThisWorkbook class?

Here's what I'm doing: In my Ribbon class, I created a public method called `InvalidateControl(string controlID)`. I need to call that method from the ThisWorkbook class based on when a certain workbook level event fires. But the only way I can see to "get" a reference to that Ribbon object is to do this...

```
    // This is all in the ThisWorkbook class
    Ribbon ribbon;
    protected override IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
    {
        this.ribbon = new Ribbon();
        return this.ribbon;
    }
```

...which seems a little smelly. I mean, I have to override `CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()` regardless; all I'm doing beyond that is maintaining a local reference to the ribbon so I can call methods against it. But it doesn't feel right. Is there another, better way to get that reference in the ThisWorkbook class? Or is this pretty acceptable?

Thanks!

Comment: Ummm.... this is weird: I got notified that someone had answered this, but there's nothing here. Did someone answer and then delete it? Hello? You out there? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A much simpler way is to create a global static variable somewhere (e.g. in ThisWorkbook).

```
public static Ribbon ribbonref;
```

Then in the code of the Ribbon class, in the event handler for the initialization event (I think the method is called `Ribbon1_StartUp()` but I'm not sure), set the variable:

```
private void Ribbon1_StartUp(object sender, EventArg e)
{
    ThisWorkbook.ribbonref = this;
}
```

(written from memory so may not be exactly right)

You can then use `ribbonref` to access your ribbon instance.

Comment: Ahhhh, I like your solution much better! Thanks very much for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Please see this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772088.aspx) page which shows the use of the Globals object:

```
Globals.Ribbons.MyRibbon.MyObject.Text = "test";
```